# Grunt task through Jenkins fails to commit to svn

Tags: jenkins, svncommit

I am creating buildinfo file using grunt task through Jenkins Job.
process.env['BUILD_NUMBER'] ,process.env['SVN_REVISION'] are available and was able to create the file .
and using  chile_process to commit the file through svn.
exec = require('child_process').exec,
            child;

```
     grunt.log.writeln("Commiting  buildinfo.js");
     child = exec("svn commit buildInfo.js -m 'jenkins is committing buildInfo' --username xxxxx --password xxxxxxxx",
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log('Error commiting Build Information file Error:' + error);
        });
```

commit works fine when i run it from terminal.
but when i run it through jenkins job it throws no error but no commit happens.
is something wrong...
I tried using  require('child_process').spawn 
this also does not commit whn i run it through jenkins woks fine from terminal though.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using  grunt-exec that works perfectly.

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-exec